# Squid Proxy - https working but http sites not working

Tags: proxy, squid

I've got a Squid proxy configuration file I have been working on for a few days. And I'm stuck on this one last issue. I finally got https URLs to work via the proxy but http URLs do not work. What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

```
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80                  

acl CONNECT method CONNECT
acl destinations dstdomain .somesite.com .someothersite.com
acl all_others dst all

acl myclients src 75.162.95.96 98.231.47.27

http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager

http_access allow CONNECT SSL_ports
http_access allow CONNECT Safe_ports

http_access deny to_localhost
http_access allow destinations

http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow myclients
# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all_others
# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 80
http_port 25000
# We recommend you to use at least the following line.
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?
#Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256
# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution?